# How do you plot a trendline for a dataset imported from Excel?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have been trying to plot a trendline for a data set of 161 mean temperature values which I imported from Excel with the help of pandas. But I can't manage to create a trendline for the data set. I've followed tutorials on YouTube and other sites, but it doesn't work. I do not get a trend line no matter what I do. I've tried something like this:

```
m, b = polyfit(data.Year, data.January, 1)
fit = m*(data.Year) + b
plt.plot(data.Year, fit)
```

This method doesn't do anything.
I'd love some help to fix this problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate method using the newer [`numpy.polynomial`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.html) package might be easier to read:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial

xdata = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
ydata = np.array([0,1,2,2.5,3.5,4,5,5.5,6,7])

poly_fit = Polynomial.fit(xdata, ydata, 1)

plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'o', *poly_fit.linspace())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `matplotlib`, you can use `polyfit` to generate a trendline:
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np`

```
# create sample data
xdata = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
ydata = np.array([0,1,2,2.5,3.5,4,5,5.5,6,7])
```

```
# calculate polynomial
z = np.polyfit(xdata, ydata, 1)
f = np.poly1d(z)
```

```
# calculate new x's and y's
x_new = np.linspace(xdata[0], xdata[-1], 50)
y_new = f(x_new)
```

```
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'o', x_new, y_new)
plt.xlim([xdata[0]-1, xdata[-1] + 1])
plt.show()
```